# Sort results by order (ascending-descending)

Tags: sorting, stata, mean

I have house price data with postcode associated. I can do `tabstat price pcode, by(price)` to get a summarized table of means but the means are sorted by `pcode`. How can I sort the mean by ascending or descending order instead of by `pcode` numeric order?

Comment: Are you using Excel?

Comment: @ClickBerry No; he's using Stata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the user-written `axis()` egen function. This is part of the `egenmore` package, which you can download by typing in Stata `ssc install egenmore`. After that you can use it as in the example below:

```
sysuse nlsw88, clear
egen meanwage = mean(wage), by(occupation)
egen Occupation = axis(meanwage occupation), label(occupation)
tabstat wage, by(Occupation) s(mean)
```